# Sind Zootiere Ausstellungsstücke?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich versuche einen generellen Begriff für Zootiere zu finden, der unterstreicht, dass sie zur Schau gestellt werden. Das Wort "Ausstellungsstück" wurde mir nahe gelegt, aber ich halte dieses Wort für nicht ganz angemessen, weil es die Zootiere implizit vergegenständlicht. Gibt es ein generelles Wort für Zootiere (oder andere Lebewesen die zur Schau gestellt werden), das andeutet, dass die Tiere zur Schau gestellt werden, ohne sie implizit zu objektivieren?

Comment: _Ausstellungsstücke_ sind wie _Exponate_ tatsächlich eher unbelebt. _Attraktionen_ trifft es auch nicht. Vielleicht (je nach Kontext) ein Neologismus? – _Schautier_ oder _Präsentiertier_ …

Comment: @Crissov *Schautier* ist hier wahrscheinlich der beste Ausdruck.

Comment: Hast du vielleicht den Satz, in den es rein soll? Ich würde gerne einen Versuch abgeben, aber die direkte Umgebung und der "Ton" spielen eine große Rolle

Comment: @Emanuel "Ich war im Zoo, allerdings als Besucher, nicht als Schautier."

Comment: @Newb "Ich war im Zoo, allerdings als Besucher, nicht als *Attraktion*." Auch wenn es im Kommentar von Crissov bereits ausgeschlossen wurde, passt es in dem Satz sehr gut.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "Besuchter" in Anführungsstrichen. Hmmm... vielleicht etwas abstrakt. Oder "Bewohner"

Comment: "im Zoo gehaltene Tiere"? "im Zoo zur Schau gestellte Tiere"?

Comment: @Emanuel den "Bewohner" finde ich absolut ideal!

Comment: Für mich hat "Zootier" genau diese Konnotation. "Die haben mich angeguckt, als wäre ich ein Zootier."

Comment: @Emanuel: Die Anführungsstriche weg. Die Bild"zeitung" hat Anführungsstriche um die Abkürzung "DDR" gemacht, um zu unterstreichen, dass sie das weder für eine Demokratie, noch eine Republik hielt. Ähnlich würden Deine Anführungsstriche bedeuten, dass die Tiere nicht besucht werden. Das werden sie aber doch, oder nicht? Auch um Bewohner wäre es falsch. Auch Metaphern werden grundsätzlich nicht mit Anführungsstrichen als solche markiert.

Comment: Wenn irgendetwas am zur Schau stellen problematisch ist, dann doch genau das, was auch beim problematisierenden Gebrauch des Wortes "objektivieren" ausgedrückt werden soll. Der letzte Satz fordert somit etwas zu tun, und es zugleich nicht zu tun. Soll das zur Schau stellen nun ausgedrückt werden, ja oder nein?

Comment: Nun, rein rechtlich sind Tiere Objekte. Wenn ich deinen Hund erschieße, ist das nur Sachbeschädigung.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anders als früher versteht sich ein moderner Zoo nicht mehr nur als Ausstellungsstätte für exotische Tiere, die dort gefangen und in Käfigen eingesperrt sind, sondern vor allem als Bildungseinrichtung, Pflegestätte und Zuchtort für seltene und bedrohte Tierarten, und Naherholunggebiet (siehe [Verband Deutscher Zoodirektoren e.V.](http://www.zoodirektoren.de/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=2&Itemid=330)).

So enthält auch die Bezeichnung Tierpfleger (früher Wärter) heute eindeutig die "Pflege" als ein charakteristischer und wichtiger Teil des Berufs schon im Namen. Es bietet sich daher an, Tiere im Zoo

> [**Pfleglinge**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pflegling)

zu nennen. Ein Pflegling kann nicht nur eine Person, sondern auch ein Tier oder eine Pflanze sein.

Des weiteren kann man Tiere, die im Zoo leben auch als

> [**Bewohner**](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Bewohner)

ihres dort für sie künstlich geschaffenen Lebensraumes bezeichnen. Zwar wird mit Begriff "Bewohner" üblicherweise ein Mensch bezeichnet, doch es gibt viele Beispiele, in denen eindeutig Tiere gemeint sind (z.B. *Meeresbewohner, Höhlenbewohner, Waldbewohner, **Zoobewohner (!)**, ...*).

Beispiel:

> Immer mehr Tiergärten bemühen sich um die Rettung bedrohter Tierarten. Sie bieten ihren **Bewohnern** viel Platz und möglichst optimale Bedingungen - und damit uns Menschen ein nachhaltiges und oft fantastisches Erlebnis <sup>[Stern](http://www.stern.de/magazin/heft/editorial-beck-und-das-recht-auf-respekt-624972.html)</sup>

Wem diese Begriffe zu ungebräuchlich oder unpassend erscheinen, sollte vielleicht lieber auf eine präzisere Umschreibung zurückgreifen:

> Die Schimpansen, die im Zoo gehalten werden.
>   In unserem Zoo leben viele Kleintiere.
>   Sie dürfern die Tiere in unserem Streichelzoo auch anfassen.

Comment: In früheren Zoos, die sich nicht vorrangig als Pflegestätte und Zuchtort sehen, sind `Ausstellungsstück` und `Exponat` treffende Bezeichnungen. Sie objektivieren die Tiere nur im Sinne der Rezipienz: Sie sind das Objekt des Rezipierens durch den Besucher. Dass die Tiere leben und nicht etwa unbelebte Dinge sind, spielt an dieser Stelle keine Rolle.

Comment: Die Frage war, wie man das zur Schau stellen unterstreicht. Die Antwort versucht das gar nicht erst.

Comment: @Takkat: Ich weiß nicht was Du unter modernen Zoos verstehst, ob alle Zoos die heute existieren schon deswegen, weil sie heutig sind, modern sind. Eine Hauptfunktion von Zoos heute ist selbstverständlich immer noch Zootiere auch zu zeigen. Die Argumentation mit politischen Gründen ist fundamental falsch, denn wenn es politische Gründe gäbe Zootiere nicht mehr zu zeigen, dann würde es ganz sicher Ausdrücke geben, die die Problematik thematisieren - wie sonst hätte man darüber sprechen können?

Comment: Außerdem muss ich nicht, um ein Defizit Deiner Antwort zu benennen, eine bessere haben, sonst hätte ich sie schon von selbst gegeben.

Comment: @userunknown doch, musst du, wenn du hier ein Defizit beklagst. Sprache ist Produkt unserer Kultur, die Lebewesen nicht mehr als Objekte betrachtet (daher auch kein Wort dafür). Man kann natürlich alle Begriffe aufführen, die es früher einmal gab, aber die passen halt heute nicht mehr.

Comment: Es gibt verschiedene Diskurse, in denen Objekte unterschiedliches, wenn auch ähnliches bedeuten. Wenn ich den Transport von etwas betrachte, dann kann für den Transport unerheblich sein, ob es sich um Menschen, Tiere oder Stühle handelt. Objekt meiner Überlegungen kann alles sein. Nur ein zwanghaftes Bedürfnis darin eine Wertung zu sehen kann versuchen hier sprachpolizeilich einzugreifen. Außerdem betrübt mich Dein Schweigen zur Frage, wie es zum politisch motivierten Bann des Zeigens kam, ohne dass darüber diskutiert wurde - oder war die Kommunikation nonverbal?

Comment: @userunknown du missinterpretierst hier meine Kernaussage - nicht das "Zeigen" wurde geächtet, sondern die Auffassung, dass ein Tier ein *Schauobjekt* oder *Ausstellungsstück* sei. Vielleicht redet ein Zookritiker noch so, aber ich habe auch da eine Verwendung dieser oder ähnlicher Ausdrücke nirgends gefunden (Du etwa?). Wenn es heute also kein geeignetes Wort mehr dafür gibt, dann sollte man das auch sagen (nur das war die Intention meiner Antwort hier).

Comment: Die Frage war aber nicht, was man stattdessen heute sagt, sondern wie man gerade die überkommene Zootierhaltung passend ausdrückt. Wenn Du die Frage verbessern willst ist eine Antwort der falsche Weg.

Comment: Ich habe diese Antwort akzeptiert, hauptsaechlich wegen ihrer Gruendlichkeit, und weil "Bewohner" wahrscheinlich meinem Beispielssatz am besten trifft. Allerdings ist der Begriff "Schautier" der, der mir generell am angebrachtesten scheint.

Comment: @Newb: wenn dir *Schautier* am besten gefällt, dann akzeptiere (oder gib wenigstens ein Upvote) doch die Antwort von DisplayName... (Crissov hat ja leider nur ein Kommentar verfasst). Mir gefällt auch die Antwort von Falkb ganz gut.

Answer (score 3):

**Schauobjekt** könnte passen (wird meist für Gegenstände benutzt, kann aber auch auf Menschen oder Tiere bezogen werden).

Für den konkreten Beispielsatz gefiele mir aber auch "Ich war im Zoo, allerdings als Besucher, nicht als **Insasse**.", da es den "Gefängnischarakter" und somit den Unterschied von Besucher zu Zootier unterstreicht. Da der Beispielsatz vermutlich eher witzig gemeint ist, würde ich hier auf die korrekte Berücksichtigung der in den letzten Jahren immer besser werdenden Unterbringung der Zootiere verzichten wollen.

Answer (score 2):

Wie bereits in einem Kommentar geschrieben: `Ausstellungsstücke` sind wie `Exponate` tatsächlich eher unbelebt.

Es wäre aber für Zootiere denkbar, aber es drückt dann eben auch aus, dass die Tiere nicht als Lebewesen, sondern als Ding betrachtet werden (was evtl. genau die zu machende Aussage wäre).

Etwas neutraler könnte man `Darsteller` nutzen. Damit würde man die Zootiere auf eine Ebene mit Schauspielern setzen (die Zootiere sind dann kein Objekt, sondern Subjekt, sie sind quasi Entertainment-Profis).

Comment: Nein, Tiere sind nicht in einem Zoo weil sie etwas *darstellen*, sondern weil sie etwas *sind*. Ein Zoo ist kein Kunstwerk.

Comment: @Twinkles nun, er kann es sein, aber nicht dadurch dass er ein Zoo ist, sondern selbst wenn es kein Zoo wäre, wäre er dann ein Kunstwerk.

Answer (score 2):

Der Begriff **Das Exemplar** wird gern verwendet, um (wie auch immer) präsentierte Vertreter aus dem Tierreich zu benennen.

Daraus ableitend wäre denkbar:

- Tierexemplar
- (tierisches) Ausstellungsexemplar
- Schauexemplar

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/in+gefangenschaft+lebende+tiere.html

Usually these animals are designated as "In Gefangenschaft lebende Tiere."

This less stresses their purpose for being looked at but more that they are unfree.

1. Vorzeige-Tier
2. **Schau-Tier (schau=show)**
3. Zoo-Tier
4. Zirkus-Tier (for reference)
5. Vorzeige-Tier - not so good

**Attraktion** would work. Die Hauptattraktion eines Zoos sind die in Gefangenschaft lebenden Tiere.

**Attraktion** is used for explaining the main feature of an event/location that draws visitors.

Die zur Schau gestellten Tiere sind die Hauptattraktion eines Zoos.

Im Zoo werden Tiere zur Schau gestellt. Diese Tiere könnte man alls Schaustelltiere bezeichen. Ähnlich Schauspiel-Tiere. ;) Or as Mentioned above.

**Schau-Spieler - Person earning a living as an actor, being shown to other people.**

**Schau-Tiere - Animals living for the purpose to be shown to other people.**